# How to find notebooks attached to a cluster in Databricks using API?

Tags: python, databricks

I run an overnight job terminating all running clusters in Azure Databricks. As each cluster might be used by multiple people, I want to find out programmatically which notebooks are attached to the each running cluster.

I use the Python Databricks Cluster API (https://github.com/crflynn/databricks-api), however I'm not against the REST API if necessary.

```
dbx_env.cluster.get_cluster(cluster_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explicit API for that, so it's not so straightforward.  One possible approach would be to analyze [audit log](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs.html#audit-events) for `attachNotebook` and `attachNotebook` events, and decide if cluster is used or not. But method may not be reliable, as events are appearing with delay, plus you need to have a job that will analyze the audit log.

Simpler solution would be to enforce auto-termination time on all interactive clusters - in this case they will be terminated automatically when nobody use them.  You can either:

- enforce that through [cluster policies](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/clusters/policies-best-practices.html)
- have a script that will go through list of clusters and check auto-termination time, setting it to something like 30 or 60 minutes.
- monitor create & edit events in audit log, and correct clusters that have no or very high auto-termination times